# How to save a Spring Data JPA entity with a composite key

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a `@Entity UserVideoRating` class which uses an an `@EmbeddedId` key called `UserVideoRatingKey`.

`UserVideoRatingKey` implements `Serializable` and overrides `equals()` and `hashCode()` and implements a `null` constructor.

I have a respository called `UserVideoRatingRepository` which implements `CrudRepository`.

In my Spring controller, to save an entity to the underlying database using Hibernate, I invoke the `UserVideoRatingRepository.save` with an instance of UserVideoRating.

Everything works ok but I see this line in the logs:

```
Hibernate: insert into user_video_rating (rating, user, video_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Why do I get these questions marks? Why are the actual values not being saved? I have looked at multiple stackoverflow questions, but I could not get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you seeing in the Log that is the DEBUG code and for debugging purpose only. If you want to check the query then just place the '?' symbol with the actual value(String should be surrounded with single cote'') and run it in your Database command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

### Why are the actual values not being saved?

Are you sure the actual values are not getting saved??

### Hibernate: insert into user_video_rating (rating, user, video_id) values (?, ?, ?)

This is the kind of statement that you will see on all of your inserts. So there is no problem with you seeing this statement in the logs.
But if you are still not able to save the values in the DB, then you are not passing correct object to the save method.